# Cannot see new drive in SSMS maintenance wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, ssms, maintenance-plans

I'm trying to setup a Backup Maintenance Plan in SSMS for Sql Server 2012, running in a failover cluster on Windows Server 2012.  The current plan backs up to the same cluster volume where the database data and transaction log files reside, and I want the backups going to a different volume, but the only volume that I can select in the maintenance plan configuration is the shared drive I am already using.  The same limitation exists when I try to manually run a backup from within SSMS - I can only see the one drive.

How can I get additional drives to show up?

I have:

1. Mapped the new cluster volume to a drive letter
2. Ensured that the sql server service account has full control permissions on that drive
3. Successfully run a backup to the new drive using T-sql

In the long term, I fully intend to move to t-sql scripted backups for the additional control and flexibility, but I'm new to this and want to get the backups on a separate drive right the heck now.

Comment: Once you added the new volume to the SQL Server, did you use the Disk Management Console to assign the volume a drive letter, and format the drive with a filesystem?

Comment: Yes, the new volume is setup - I can save a backup there using t-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 for sensibly wanting to get the backups on a separate drive. However, if the new cluster volume is on the same SAN, you're not really accomplishing much. It would likely be much better to run backups to a file share on a totally different system.

As a workaround, you can easily add an "Execute T-SQL Statement" task to your Maintenance Plan to manually specify the backup statement:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to the original question - the new volume became browse-able after restarting the agent.  (But Max's workaround is still great)